Docker log retrieval issue with local log driver
EDIT:  this appears to be a problem with a long string of zeros getting dumped into the local logs; docker can't cope with this.  Since sometimes the machine running our app loses power, when it comes back the logs can get corrupted in a way which should be recoverable, but which isn't by the Docker tools (at least as of Docker 24)
I’ve got an application running under Docker (more info below) on an aarch64 Ubuntu 20.04 system, and recently some issues with the logs have come up.
I can retrieve logs from the container start (currently a few days ago, 2024-08-29) up until 2024-08-31 using docker logs -t container-id, but at a point on that date, this happens:
2024-08-31T11:28:56.390605163-07:00 DEBUG:root:PIN states: 
2024-08-31T11:28:56.390655787-07:00  Input PIN                                 Value
Error grabbing logs: error unmarshalling log entry (size=5386): proto: LogEntry: illegal tag 0 (wire type 6)

This container is still running, and I can obtain recent logs using the -n  flag:
# docker logs -n 100000 -t 26159da5d173c63ec670f6e2ccf3b0ab95e7f6ac5942ab405797d9d8fdb27a60 |head 
2024-09-03T04:24:26.567111463-07:00 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.olyns.com:443 "POST /v2/api/collector/welcome HTTP/1.1" 200 257

…but trying to retrieve using the --since and --until flags (which usually works) gives me a similar error:
# docker logs --since 5m -t 26159da5d173c63ec670f6e2ccf3b0ab95e7f6ac5942ab405797d9d8fdb27a60 
Error grabbing logs: log message is too large (108229732 > 1000000)

In the container directory (/var/lib/docker/containers/<id>/local-logs) there are files:
total 53040
-rw-r----- 1 root root 21403176 Sep  3 13:40 container.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10987441 Sep  2 17:46 container.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10828104 Sep  1 19:01 container.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root root 11081548 Aug 31 23:08 container.log.3.gz

… and they seem to have data, but they’re in a format that has timestamps in binary (so, recoverable, but not convenient).
Info about this system:
$ uname -a
Linux 27A00024 5.10.120-rt70-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Sep 19 19:50:25 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

there is plenty of disk space (24GB avail on /, which is where /var is), and the Docker version is:
Docker version 24.0.7, build 24.0.7-0ubuntu2~20.04.1
In docker-compose.yml, this container is set up with the local logging driver:
    logging:
      driver: "local"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
        max-file: "5"

...I'd love any thoughts about what's going on and/or how to prevent it.  Another system has recently started displaying a similar issue.
